# Neon Text Effect with Compound Shapes - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, illustrator-effects, path-effects

I'm following this tutorial for neon effects in Illustrator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWSFGIEAz4s

However, whenever I offset the path, for some reason some of my letters remain filled in and some of them turn into outlines? I don't understand what I can do to stop this from happening. I can't have some of the letters filled in and some not - it doesn't work for the neon look.

I'm using Illustrator 2019, version 23.0.3. The only difference I have between the tutorial and my file is that I didn't start with a font, I started with a logo (which is just an outlined version of the font originally).

What am I missing?

[image: Offset in Illustrator]

Comment: Check at first if some of your letters are not only outlined fonts, but have also outlined strokes. Find the differences by giving to all letters a thin colored stroke and fill all with another color. Then you can normalize all to have same structure.

Comment: @user287001 they all look and behave the same way prior to the offset - same stroke/fill. Only after the offset do they change from fill to outlined.

Comment: The "O" is a compound shape.. same as an R, P, Q, A, B, or D would be. "S" is *not* a compound shape (there's no "hole" in it). Is it that the compound shapes are "filling in"?

Comment: @Scott yes now that you point it out only the compound shapes are filling in. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Well, I can't replicate the issue. There must be something unique about the artwork you are using, or some step which may not be correct - I didn't watch the video.

Comment: @Scott I've added a link above that has a sample of the file im working with. Maybe you could take a look and see if I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry becca. I won't download random files from the internet. Nothing personal, just a blanket policy.